# How to Serialize a Type to specified database columns

Tags: haskell, postgresql-simple

I am using postgresql-simple in a haskell application, and i want to be able to serialize a data type to a row in my database that doesn't have a 1 to 1 mapping of the record fields used in the data type  because i am using them in other data types. (I'm Fairly New to Haskell but I think this involves using the Identifier data constructor).

Example I have a database table Users with the following columns: user_id, email, name, password, address, phone_number

now I have a type with the following format:

```
data UserDetails = UserDetails {
  user_id :: Int,
  email :: Text,
  phone_number :: Maybe (Text),
  password :: Text,
  name :: Maybe (Text),
  address :: Maybe (Text),
} deriving (Show, Generic, FromRow)
```

And i can have a generic ToRow implemented for this type no problem since the record fields are the same as the column names, but I have another type that i want to generate a ToRow instance for which is:

```
data UserEditDetails = UserEditDetails {
  ued_email :: Maybe (Email),
  ued_phone_number :: Maybe (Text),
  ued_address :: Maybe (Text),
  ued_name :: Maybe (Text),
} deriving (Show, Generic)
```

how would i implement a ToRow instance of this type or more generally how can i write a ToRow instance like the following pseudo code

```
instance ToRow UserEditDetails where
  toRow a = (columnname, ued_email a)... etc
```

hopefully it has a function similar to Aeson where you can easily write something like:

```
instance ToJSON Login where
  toJSON = genericToJSON defaultOptions { fieldLabelModifier = drop 4 }
```

but i havent found this.

Comment: What is `ToRow`?

Comment: Sorry the ToRow is a typeclass for postgresql-simple i will edit the question to show that

Answer (score 1):

`postgresql-simple` doesn't pay any attention to database column names.  It just expects the count and order of columns serialized or deserialized by the `ToRow`/`FromRow` instances will match the count and order of columns in the SQL query.  You can use the generic instance for `ToRow UserEditDetails` as long as the query you're feeding it to matches the four columns in the right order.  For example, if you have the following definition and generic `ToRow` instance:

```
data UserEditDetails = UserEditDetails
  { ued_email :: Maybe Text
  , ued_phone_number :: Maybe Text
  , ued_address :: Maybe Text
  , ued_name :: Maybe Text
  } deriving (Show, Generic, ToRow)
```

then I believe the following query will work fine:

```
do let q = "update user_table set email=?, phone_number=?, address=?, name=? "
           ++ "where user_id=?"
   execute conn q $ (UserEditDetails
                      (Just "me@example.invalid")
                      (Just "555-1212")
                      (Just "123 Fake Street")
                      (Just "Bob Jones"))
                    :. Only (15 :: Int)  -- user_id 15
```

Note that the generic instances from `FromRow` and `ToRow` are equivalent to:

```
instance ToRow UserEditDetails where
  toRow (UserEditDetails a b c d) = [toField a, toField b, toField c, toField d]
instance FromRow UserEditDetails where
  fromRow = UserEditDetails <$> field <*> field <*> field <*> field
```

The fields are anonymous and there's no place to give specific database columns anyway.

Comment: But when i save the type UserDetails type into my database i save it into a table with more columns than type fields are present and each record field maps accordingly to the column of the same name in the database.

Comment: How do you save your `UserDetails` type into your database?  Is it not with an `insert` query?